# red5 oflaDemo RTMP stream URL?

Tags: red5, rtmp

I am setting up a screen sharing tool by creating a RTMP stream and broadcasting it via red5 server.

I am using the oflaDemo and creating a stream in the name of screen_share. I succeeded in making it work in JWPlayer.

I am trying to use broadcast to a mobile RTMP player app. To stream sample videos in oflaDemo, I used the URL rtmp://red5.myserver.com/oflaDemo/hobbit_v6.flv and it works.

What will be the standard RTMP url for the screen_share stream ??

I tried rtmp://red5.my_server.com/oflaDemo/screen_share and it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I use the screen share with the [plugin](https://github.com/deleolajide/red5-screenshare) with red5, and I update the screenshare.jnlp file to fit my case.

The screenshare.jnlp will be

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<jnlp spec='1.0+' codebase='http://my.red5.ip:5080/screenshare'> 
    <information> 
        <title>Red5 ScreenShare</title> 
        <vendor>Dele Olajide</vendor> 
        <homepage>http://code.google.com/p/red5screnshare/</homepage>
        <description>Red5 ScreenShare</description> 
        <description kind='short'>An Open Source Screen Share Java application for Adobe Flash using Red5</description> 
        <offline-allowed/> 
    </information>
    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security> 
    <resources> 
    <j2se version='1.6+'/> 
        <jar href='screenshare.jar'/> 
    </resources> 
    <application-desc main-class='org.redfire.screen.ScreenShare'>
        <argument>my.red5.ip</argument> 
        <argument>screenshare</argument> 
        <argument>1935</argument> 
        <argument>screen_share</argument>   
        <argument>flashsv2</argument>       
        <argument>10</argument>         
        <argument>1024</argument>   
        <argument>768</argument>        
    </application-desc> 
</jnlp>
```

When user download and run the jnlp with JAVA, start to share screen,
The rmtp url will be:

```
rmtp://my.red5.ip/screenshare/screen_share
```

hope this information can help you.